How to deploy node.js project in Azure-devops uisng CI/CD pipeline
I am developing a  Node.JS project package.json and app.js (app.js is the main file of the project). I am using postgresql, I've placed all db related configuration under environmental variables.
I am trying to deploy the below project in Azure DevOps using CI/CD pipeline. This is a web app using Azure Repos.
Current Implementation:
Without CI/CD pipeline, following the below method to deploy the code and it's working fine.
Currently under Deployment Center Selected following items:

Source: Azure Repos
Azure Repos:
Project: Project Name
Repo: Repo name
Branch: branch
Build: Azure pipelines

Error I am getting after deployment:
In the logs I can see the deployment success, but when I hit the URL of the Node.js app, I see This Page isn't working right now or Internal server 500.
Steps I have followed:

Step 1: I am using Azure Repo
Please Note: I am using Classic Editor

Step 2: Clicking pipelines (blade) --> pipelines --> New pipeline

Step 2.1: Clicking pipeline (Build Pipeline) Entering the following fields:

Name: Node-JS BackEnd Project
Agent Pool: Azure pipelines
Agent Specification: Windows Latest


Step 2.2: Get sourceMapsEnabled (My-Repo and Branch)

Step 2.3: Selecting AgentJob (npm Editing Following Fields):

Task Version: 1
Display Name: npm install
Command: install
Working folder that contains package.json: ./



NOTE: LEFT OTHER OPTIONS AS IT IS in Step 2.3

Step 2.4: Selected Copy Files to (Edited Following Details):

Task Version: 2
Display Name: Copy Files to: ./
Source Folder: ./
Contents: ***.js, ***.json,
Target Folder: ./



NOTE: LEFT OTHER OPTIONS AS IT IS in Step 2.4

Step 2.5: Selected Archive Files LEFT ALL OPTIONS AS IT IS:
1.Archive Type: zip

Step 2.6: Publish artifacts: drop LEFT ALL OPTIONS AS IT IS


After the above steps, I ran the build, which was successful, and I can see the updated code in    artifacts.

Step 3: In Pipelines Blade Clicked (Releases) Create Release.

Step 3.1: Added by Artifact

Step 3.2: Clicked Run On Agent and added (Azure App Service deploy)

Step 3.3: Edited Following fields in Azure App Service deploy:

Task Version: 4
Display Name: App service deploy
Connection Type: Azure Resource Manager
Azure Subscription: xxxxxx
App Service Type: Web app on Windows
App Service name: node-js-backend-project
Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip



NOTE: OTHER OPTIONS IN  Step 3.3 LEFT AS IT IS
After the above steps, I clicked create release - I can see all the jobs success. When I am hitting the backend URL I am getting the same issue (Internal server 500 error).
Code:
    //Package.json:
    {
    "name":"Node-backend-project",
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "main":"app.js"
    "scripts":{
        "start" : "nodemon app.js",
        "dev": "node app.js"
    }
    "dependencies":{
        "@azure/storage-blob":"^12.0.0",
        "axios":"^1.6.2",
        "cors":"^2.8.5",
        "dotenv":"^16.3.1",
        "express":"^4.18.1",
        "express-fileupload":"^1.4.3",
        "lowdb":"^1.0.0",
        "passport":"^0.6.0",
    }
    }

    //app.js
    const express = require("express");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
    const router = require("./routes/index");
    const pool = require("./db");
    require("dotenv").config();
    const upload = require("express-fileupload");
    const { pipeline } = require("stream")
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    const limiter = rateLimit({
        WindowMs:12*60*1000,
        max:70,
        standardHeaders:true,
        legacyHeaders:false,
    })
    
    app.use();
    app.use(cors());
    app.options('*', cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extend:false}));
    app.use(router);
    app.use(upload());
    
    async function testConnection() {
    try {
        const client = await pool.conect();
        client.release();
    }catch(err){
        console.error("Error", err)
    }
    
    app.listen(port, async () => {
        await testConnection();
    })
    }

I have tried many solutions from StackOverflow and Microsoft documentation (where they use only Hello World program to deploy) but no solutions are working for me. Instead of Azure App Service, I tried with Azure Web App deploy also, but I am getting the same result. I have copied and pasted the web.config file (renamed the index.js to app.js) from the below StackOverflow link:
Azure Node.js Internal Server Error from index.js file
I am not clear on what I am doing wrong. From the front-end when I am hitting the dev URL I can see that I am getting internal server error (500 error).
Could anyone guide me to successfully host the Node.js app in Azure DevOps using CI/CD pipeline? Thanks in Advance!

These are my classic CI-CD steps to deploy a Node.js web app.
NodeJsWebAPP-CI

Node.js tool installer


Version Spec: Specific your target Node.js version


Command line



    npm install
    npm run build --if-present
    npm run test --if-present


Archive files


Root folder or file to archive: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
Archive file to create: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
Replace existing archive


Publish Pipeline Artifacts


File or directory path: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
Artifact name: Your artifact name



NodeJSWebAPP-CD

Select your CI pipeline as the artifact

Azure App Service deploy


Azure subscription: Your ARM service connection or Your Subscription.
App Service name: Your app name
Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip
Additional Deployment Options->check Select deployment method
Deployment method: Web Deploy
Take App Offline: Uncheck




I tried the above solution, I am getting App service is offline.

Hi @Rohan, have you unchecked the Take App Offline option of Azure App Service deploy task?

Hi @ Ziyang Liu-MSFT, yes I have unchecked the Take App offline

Please check if there is a custom app_offline.htm file in the root of your application. If there is, please remove it.
